# Mac App Store sandboxing and read-only SQLite DB in .APP bundle

Tags: sqlite, mac-app-store, readonly, sandbox

I'm working on Mac App Store sandboxing but have an app that was rejected from the store based on detected read/write access to an SQLite database file located in my .APP bundle.  However, I only need read access to this file, so the .APP bundle is a good location.  I'm using FMDB, which by default opens SQLite databases using **sqlite3_open** unless you call FMDB's openWithFlags: method, which instead calls **sqlite3_open_v2** using the *flags* parameter.

My question: If I use **sqlite3_open_v2** with the **SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY** flag, is it equivalent to file system read-only access?  If read-only access to the database means something different than file system read-only access, then the app will be rejected again.  The SQLite documentation for **SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY** states (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html):

*"The database is opened in read-only mode. If the database does not already exist, an error is returned."*

But, this doesn't seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted my app with the SQLITE_READ_ONLY flag, and the app was accepted to the App Store.  This leads me to believe that the SQLITE_OPEN-READONLY flag is equivalent to file system read-only mode.